# Placing Javascript code within a string?

Tags: javascript, string, module

I'm trying to have the ability to put Javascript code within strings (inside Javascript). I'm using my own gruntjs task to read all the javascript files and place it within strings.

`var modules = [];
modules['filename.js'] = "code here...."`

This works for simple Javascript classes, but when putting external libraries in such format (JQuery, Ember.js, Underscore) it will fail. I am replacing each `"` inside the code to `\"`. But I'm still getting syntax errors. I'm thinking it may have to do with some RegEx, or, in some parts they might have escaped some double quotes.

**Edit:** The code is found here: https://github.com/TheHydroImpulse/resolve.js
But specifically the build script (gruntjs) is here: https://github.com/TheHydroImpulse/resolve.js/blob/master/examples/basic/grunt.js

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried encoding/decoding the content of the JS files?

Comment: In what sense? Meaning UTF8 or something?

Comment: Maybe base64 or similar?

Comment: No, I mean using [encoreURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) / [decodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

Comment: Would this not render special characters useless? Or would I have to re-encode before using the contents of the stringified code?

Comment: encode > store in strings > decode > use

Comment: How about any backslashes already present in the code before you replace `"` with `\"`?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes that's what I thought, but escaping both `\"` and `"` has the same effect, unless I'm escaping them wrong.

Comment: @Daniel: You don't want to escape only `\"` -- you want to escape _all_ backslashes in the original code.

Comment: So far so good, I'm using the following regex: ```contents = contents.replace(new RegExp("\\", "g"), "\\\\");
    contents = contents.replace(new RegExp("\\\"", "g"), "\"");```

Comment: Ok, so it seems like I forgot to remove the escaped backslashes before parsing on the code. Still errors on external libraries though...

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Indeed it works now (maybe you'd want to leave an answer containing the encode / decode, etc...). Not sure why I was still escaping special characters (most notably, \, and "), but when I encode the string, I don't need to escape anything at all. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Happy to know it works! I've added my suggestion as an answer as requested :)

Comment: Another thing you may want to escape is the newline character "\n". Literal newlines within strings breaks javascript (at least in browsers, not sure about engines like node). So you need to replace them with "\n".

Comment: @slebetman Thanks. All the javascript is minified before going into strings, but for templates (views), that's what I had to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to keep intact the JS code, you'll have to encode it before storing it to a string, and decode the string before using it.

Both operations can be carried out with built-in JavaScript functions [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) and [decodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Wild stab in the dark here (just became halloween here under an hour ago) but maybe you are not putting it all into one line, and therefore not handling multiline strings correctly...

Or maybe you are crushing the files into one line, and not adding semi-colons where necessary.

I recommend you use a tool for minifying, like uglify and then try it with the libraries as a single line of minified javascript.

Comment: Yes UglifyJS is being uses to minify and concatenate everything. My system works under simple scripts with multiple lines. In Chrome, it doesn't seem to display the whole contents of the minified and concatenated file and only shows a small portion of it.